# Error when upgrading from Joomla 2.5 to 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, upgrade

I finally took on my last upgrade to have all my joomla installs on their current version. so on this last one during the install of the upgrade package. i am now getting a white page and with error reporting turned on, this error from admin:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/plugins/system/jqueryintegrator/jqueryintegrator.php on line 38

Fatal error: Call to undefined method RuntimeException::get() in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/libraries/joomla/error/error.php on line 797
```

and this from the frontend:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/plugins/system/jqueryintegrator/jqueryintegrator.php on line 38

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplicationSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/plugins/system/jcemediabox/jcemediabox.php on line 251

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplicationCms::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/libraries/cms/application/site.php on line 279

Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/modules/mod_showplus/mod_showplus.php on line 45

Warning: require_once(/home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/modules/mod_showplusDShelper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/modules/mod_showplus/mod_showplus.php on line 45

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/modules/mod_showplusDShelper.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/tendesig/public_html/manabigama.com/modules/mod_showplus/mod_showplus.php on line 45
```

Comment: **Strict standarts** is a common php 5.4+ error. You could hide it with .htaccess or custom php.ini. As for last two errors you have to upgrade `mod_showplus` to a joomla 3 compatible version.

Comment: the DS constant is no longer available, you can redefine it in the module if you don't find an update (defined('DS')||define('DS','/');

Answer (score 2):

According to your error reports, the following plugins/modules are causing problems:

1. [jQuery Integrator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/12995) (Plugin)

   - According to the [developers website](http://tushev.org/web/joomla-extensions/item/41-jquery-integrator), the plugin is no longer supported. In addition, it's not recommended to activate the plugin for the admin area:

     > Warning: do not activate jQuery at backend ('activate at backend as
     >   well' parameter in advanced tab) unless you're completely sure about
     >   what are you doing. jQuery is absolutely unnecessary in adminpanel,
     >   and those extensions that use it, bring jQuery with them
     >   automatically. <sup>[tushev.org](http://tushev.org/web/joomla-extensions/item/41-jquery-integrator)</sup>

     There are other alternatives available here, but for Joomla 3.x, you might not even need a plugin to use jQuery, as it is now the [default javascript library](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks) in Joomla. Most extensions will load it if needed, and you also can load jQuery by adding `<?php JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); ?>` to your template or extension file.
2. [JCE Media Box](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/mediabox) (plugin)

   - The plugin is probably not updated. Please download the latest version from the link above, and install it.
3. [showplus](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-mootools-slideshow/15727) (module)

   - This slideshow module reports several errors. Downloading and installing the latest Joomla 3-compatible version will probably solve your problems.

(In order to hide the Strict Standards errors, you can go to Global Configuration → Server tab → Error Reporting and set it to `None`. This will probably not get rid of the Fatal error, though, and doesn't actually solve anything.)